# Modulus and Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

How do I calculate $ 11^{23} \bmod{163} $ using fermat's little theorem ?

Comment: What does Fermat's Little Theorem say, do you remember?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem won't help here; 23 is less than 162. You're better off using binary exponentiation.

Comment: you can find this theorem here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Notice $163$ is prime, so by fermat we have $11^{23}= 11^{0\cdot(163-1)+23}\equiv11^{23}\bmod 163$

So we have reduced to problem to calculating $163^{23}$. Notice $23=10111$ in binary and so $11^{23}=11^{16}\cdot11^4\cdot11^2\cdot11$.

We can calculate the powers of two by squaring the previous

$11\equiv 11$

$11^2\equiv 121$

$11^4\equiv 134$

$11^8 \equiv 26$

$11^{16} \equiv 24$

So $11^{23}\equiv 11\cdot121\cdot134\cdot24\equiv 116\bmod 163$

Comment: What are you saying? Your first line showed that $11^{23} \equiv 11^{23} \pmod {163}$ and then you say that we have to calculate $163^{23}$ but that is $0 \pmod {163}$. Fermat doesn't help at all here.

Comment: it's a joke.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: im not sure how you would use format's to solve this. i think dREaM's method here will be by far the simplest.

Comment: fermat will not work, fermat's theorem is just the simple observation that the order of any element $\mathbb Z_p$ is a divisor of $p-1$. This cannot be improved at all, in fact, in this case the order of $11$ is precisely $162$, so there is nothing to be done.